# Rebus: My Random Diary Notes

Tags: wordplay, rebus, movies

Checkout these notes from a random page of my diary and tell what it indirectly refers to.

> - I have to join the Karate class next week.
> - I bumped my head on the wall yesterday.
> - I had my break fast early today.
> - I met my childhood friend Thomas yesterday.
> - We partied so hard yesterday night.
> - I attended the job interview last wednesday.
> - I lost my mobile last week.
> - I will buy a new one tomorrow.

**HINT1**

> Check the tags.

**HINT2**

> The first and last notes are different from the rest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

> Back to the Future

since

> The first and last notes refer to future events, but the middle is all recounting past events.

Comment: Perfect. You got it. :)

Answer (score 1):

#### This is not the intended answer...confirmed by OP

I think

> These time spans gives us the idea of when the movies were released. So 'today' might mean that it is on the theaters right now, 'Yesterday' means that it has been 2 or 3 years and so on...

---

I have to join the Karate class next week.

> **Kung-fu Panda 3** releasing this April.

I bumped my head on the wall yesterday.

> **Strike Back** (released in 2010)

I had my break fast early today.

> No idea

I met my childhood friend Thomas yesterday.

> **Thomas and Friends : Curious Cargo** released in 2012

We partied so hard yesterday night.

> **Search Party** released in 2014

I attended the job interview last Wednesday.

> **Steve Jobs** released in 2015 or
>  **Pirates of Silicon Valley** released in 1999

I lost my mobile last week.

> **Rob the Mob** released in 2014

I will buy a new one tomorrow.

> **Raees** releasing this July... (Raees = Rich) :p

Comment: It's a rebus. Not a riddle. :)

Comment: Will post a new hint later. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and least probable answer would be

> The Notebook

But, since that seems improbable, it may be

> Three Weeks

Since

> All of these actions mentioned in the question fall in a time span of three weeks, the previous, the current, and the next.

Comment: Sorry. That's not it. Will add more hints later, if no one else finds it.

Answer (score 0):

Do soap operas count as movies?

> Days of Our Lives ([link](http://www.nbc.com/days-of-our-lives))

Comment: Sorry. It is not.